# How can i Show / Hide Div when i navigate from initial page to another and then come back to initial page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have multiple html pages
I have some specific content in Home page, its content should not be changed when the page is refreshed or reloaded.
But when I navigate to other pages and then come back to Home page, I would like to show / hide div or section of html in the Home page. 
How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.referrer` to get the previous page URL and hide the element you want to hide using a condition.

```
//element to hide
var boxA = document.querySelector('.boxA');
//last page url
var lastPage = document.referrer.split("/").pop();
//checking if element exist and previous page is page B   
if(boxA && lastPage === 'b.html' ){
  boxA.style.display = 'none';
}
```

StackOverflow snippet doesn't support multiple html pages, please check this plunker to understand the above code better https://plnkr.co/edit/sbBIHf1RZA7YMTL4sJfd?p=preview

Comment: Hi @azs06, thanks for the repl. Can i get the solution for multiple pages, because i cant give the pages in the script.

Comment: @Ravichand could you explain the problem? This solution should work any number of pages, obviously page URL would be different for your situation, are you having trouble adding script to your pages?

Answer (score 0):

Add a querystring to the url using JS on page B, then check for it on page A and remove/modify content as needed:

```
// Set url parameter:

var myURL = document.location;
document.location = myURL + "?a=parameter";


// Check for url parameter:

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Link from page B to page A with a url querystring. Something like

```
https://mywebsite.com/a?myParam=1
```

Then on page A.

```
var myParam = location.search.split('myParam=')[1]
if(myParam == 1){
document.getElementById('hideDiv').style.display = 'none';
}
```